# Bessel Correction and Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, variance, geometric-brownian, stochastic-drift

Does it make sense to use bessel's correction for standard deviation and variance when fitting the drift and volatility parameters of geometric brownian motion to historical return data for a security. I've seen implementations without it but fail to see how that's defensible when historical data is essentially a sample.